# ionicMultilingual JSON issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

I am facing an issue while translating from one language to other. when I use code

```
this.translate.use('en');  // for any language
```

I am not able to translate, what I get from JSON file is -

```
"{\n  \"Status\": \"Task Status\"\n}\n"
```

Problem is json file. Its reading in stringify format, appending backslash and \n.

And if I use

```
setTranslation()
```

e.g.

```
this.translate.setTranslation('en', { "Status": "Task Status" });
```

then language is translated successfully.

As of now I am using hindi and english language to translate. So this.translate results in:

```
this.translate.use('hi');

hi: Object { _body: "{\n  \"Task Listing\": \"कार्य सूची\",\n  \"Task Type\": \"कार्य प्रकार\",\n  \"Task Status\": \"कार्य स्थिति\",\n  \"Mobile\": \"मोबाइल\",\n  \"Type\": \"प्रकार\",\n  \"Status\": \"स्थिति\"\n}\n", status: 200, ok: true, … }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by adding HttpClientModule in *app.module.ts* solves my problem.

previously I was using Http but angular 4+ uses HttpClient, So I changed.

#### app.module.ts

`imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader : {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],`

Answer (score 0):

**You need to parse JSON**

```
eg. JSON.parse(jsonString);

var tempJson="{\n  \"Status\": \"Task Status\"\n}\n"  //this is ur string
Eg. var data=JSON.parse(tempJson)
console.log(data)
```

Comment: I am getting this in Object - Store-> translations->hi: {…}
​​​​
_body: "{\n  \"Task Listing\": \"कार्य सूची\",\n  \"Task Type\": \"कार्य प्रकार\",\n  \"Task Status\": \"कार्य स्थिति\",\n  \"Mobile\": \"मोबाइल\",\n  \"Type\": \"प्रकार\",\n  \"Status\": \"स्थिति\"\n}\n", after using translation method "use" i.e. `this.translation.use('hi');`  So where should I Parse in code?

Comment: The whole string u need to parse

Comment: I can not parse this Object string, because it is in built function which directly translates into the language i have Provided in 'use('hi')' function( using hi.json file). I had tried that also.

Comment: _expected is this format_ **hi: {…}
Mobile: "मोबाइल"
Status: "स्थिति"
"Task Listing": "कार्य सूची"
"Task Status": "कार्य स्थिति"
"Task Type": "कार्य प्रकार"
Type: "प्रकार"**  and I am getting this - **hi: {…} ​​​​ _body: "{\n \"Task Listing\":....**  Unable to use from i18n file.